# How Do I Format UILabel To Display From 2 UIPickerView Components?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components.

I want a UILabel to display the selected row.  Right now I have 2 UILabels side-by-side but I think it would make more sense to have one to display the data.

The UIPickerView's 1st component is array of numbers 1-500, the 2nd component is array of strings just ".0lb, and 1/2lb".

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:700];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 1000 ; ++i)
       [pickerArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]]; 
pickerArrayHalf = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
[pickerArrayHalf addObject:@".0 lb"];
[pickerArrayHalf addObject:@"1/2 lb"];
```

I am currently using this code to feed into the 2 UILabels:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==1)
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected weight 1: %@. Index of  array: %i", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row], row);
            NSString *weightSelected;
            weightSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];
            weightLabel.text = weightSelected;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected weight 2: %@. Index of  array: %i", [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row], row);
            NSString *weightSelected;
            weightSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row]];
            weightLabel2.text = weightSelected;
        }
    }
```

The idea for the 1 UILabel over the 2 currently is because this string should be a number, like "50.0" or "200 1/2", etc.

Comment: you want to put values from both the picker component into label?

Comment: Yes, component 1 gives number and component 2 gives the accessory, such as 1/2 or 0.  It will be easier to use and more efficient as 1 label rather than 2 separate labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==1)
    {
       NSMutableString *labelText = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected weight 1: %@. Index of  array: %i", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

            [labelText appendFormat:@"%@", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected weight 2: %@. Index of  array: %i", [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row], row);

           [labelText appendFormat:@"%@", [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row]];

        }
        weightLabel2.text = labelText;
        [labelText release];
    }
```

**Updated :**

Declare two instance variable in your .h file I am naming and using them as follows

```
NSMutableString *firstComponentText;
NSMutableString *secondComponentText;
```

alloc init above mutable strings in `viewDidLoad` as `[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];`

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==1)
    {

        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected weight 1: %@. Index of  array: %i", [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

            [firstComponentText setString:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Selected weight 2: %@. Index of  array: %i", [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row], row);

           [secondComponentText setString:[pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row]];

        }
        weightLabel2.text = [firstComponentText stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",secondComponentText];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ravin, I tried this code but unfortunately it is not doing what I was asking.  Instead, it is setting the label to the last row I selected.  What I was looking for was 1 label that would have both values at the same time, like 100 (from component 1) + .0 or 1/2 (from component 2).

Comment: It means when you change values?

Comment: Ok, just image component one is bills, like $100, and component 2 is like coints, so .50 cents, or 25 cents, etc.  So if user wants to enter $75.99, they select 75 in left component, and .99 in component 2.  So the label needs to update when either component is selected.

Comment: The code above updates the UILabel with the last selected value, regardless of column. So if I picked "50" from column 1, it would show "50", but then when I go to the second column and select "1/2", it replaces the "50" with "1/2", instead of adding them together to get "50 1/2".

Comment: works great! thanks, just to tell u `[secondComponentText:[pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row]];` should be `[secondComponentText setString:[pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row]];`.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You can append your string when the row in second column is selected by using this

```
weightSelected = [weightSelected stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [pickerArrayHalf objectAtIndex:row]];
```

and then set it to a single UILabel.